# how to recall an integer in a string in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am just trying to recall an integer in a string as below;

```
x=1
y=4
$Data <<EOD
12 x
22 y
EOD
print $Data
```

Right now, when I output the above lines, it would print

```
12 x
22 y
```

However, I am interested to see the output when I print $Data like;

```
12 1
22 4
```

I used the $ sign behind the integers x and y but it didn't work and same is true using quotation marks.
Is there anyway to get around it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing your overall goal it is hard to say what the best answer is. If you will not be changing the values of x and y in between uses of $Data then one solution is to expand x and y when writing $Data rather than when reading it:

```
set print $Data
print sprintf("%d 12", x)
print sprintf("%d 22", y)
unset print

plot $Data using 1:2 with linespoints
```

If you truly need to extract a string "foo" from each line of $Data and retrieve the current value of a variable with that name:

```
$Data << EOD
    x 12
    y 22
EOD

x = 3; y = 5
do for [ i=1: |$Data| ] {
    print value(word($Data[i],1)), " ", word($Data[i],2)
}
    3 12
    5 22
```

Note that you must add an explicit space in the middle of the `print` statement.

To do this inside a plot command:

**Edit**: Apparently the program gets confused if the variable name read in is specifically "x" because that is also the default name of the dependent variable along the horizontal axis.  You can remove this ambiguity by temporarily renamed the default name for the dependent variable (the program calls this a "dummy" name).

```
set dummy not_really_x
plot $Data using (value(strcol(1))) : (column(2)) with linespoints
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the help and snipped codes. The goal is to retrieve the current values and store them in the $Data so that I can use them to plot some data.

Comment: Then it sounds like the first example given in the answer will suffice. I will amend it to show the plot command.

Comment: Hi Ethan, I don't know when I plot using this command, the first x value always 0. It is plotting 0 12 instead on 3 12. Have you checked the output?

Comment: If you plot the second snipped could, you would be able to see what I am talking about!

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean.  The problem seems to be use of the variable name "x".  I think the program successfully places an "x" in the plot command but then gets confused as to whether that refers to the current x coordinate or the value of a variable named x.  It works correctly if you replace the variable name "x" with "w".  Another fix is to temporarily change the placeholder name for the independent variable on the horizontal axis to something other than "x".  The command is `set dummy <name>`. I will modify the code snippet to show this.

Comment: Many thanks Ethan! It worked! I have another question for you, what if I swap the columns meaning 12;22 first column instead? The do for loop doesn't seem to retrieve the values of x and y.

Comment: Your revised question is not clear to me.  Do you mean the contents of the data are changed, or the `using` spec, or something else?  Please edit the original question to add the altered $Data or `using`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. i just edited the post to make it more clear.

Comment: `set dummy fake_x, fake_y; plot $Data using (column(1)) : (value(strcol(2)))`

Comment: Many thanks Ethan again for the help! Do you know by any chance what would  |$Data| be in the do for loop for gnuplot version 5.0.  |$Data| does seem to work in the do for loop for version 5.2 between when I switch to older machine, which has v5.0, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Same is true inside the word($Data[i],2).

Comment: Reading the manual of both version, it doesn't seem to be in version 5.0

Comment: Yes, treating a datablock as an indexable array of strings was introduced in version 5.2